# FullCalendar React eventClick/ dateClick not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm starting to test out FullCalendar, but cant seem to figure this part out. I have the component loading fine, my events being pulled by RTK Query and displaying fine, but the eventClick and dateClick methods arent firing at all. At the moment, I'm not doing anything fancy, just setting an alert. From the docs, eventClick (which does not require any additional plugin) and dateClick (which does and I have it installed) should be set up as props for the component and thats pretty much it. Looking around I came across others with the same issue, but in other frameworks like VueJS, most of them seem to be resolved with adjusting the css, however for the react case the component and plugins are pulling the css behind the scenes, and so it does not seem like they should be the source of the issue. If anyone has any insight on this, or can spot where I'm going wrong, I'd appreciate any help/ feedback.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { useGetUserScheduleVisitsQuery } from '../../redux/apiSlice';
import { UserContext } from '../userviews/UserContext';
import ScheduleVisit from '../visitviews/ScheduleVisit';

export default function Schedule () {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
    const userId = user._id

    const { data: visits, isSuccess, isLoading} = useGetUserScheduleVisitsQuery(userId)

    const handleDateClick = () => {
        alert("clicked")
    }

    const handleEventClick = (arg) => {
        alert(arg.event.title)
        alert(arg.event.start)
    }

    return (
        <FullCalendar
            plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ]}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
            headerToolbar= {{
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            }}
            events={visits}
            dateClick={handleDateClick}
            eventClick={handleEventClick}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: I set up a codesandbox, and of course, the click events work just fine... https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-test-f96odb

Comment: So I shut down the port and restarted the app, now it works... :/ doesn't explain anything though...

Answer (score 0):

add the  editable={true} prop to the FullCalendar Component and then try again

```
<FullCalendar
        plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        headerToolbar= {{
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        }}
        events={visits}
        dateClick={handleDateClick}
        eventClick={handleEventClick}
        editable={true}

    />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).